# use git repo of android library

Tags: android, git, android-studio, jar, repo

I use AQuery, I have the last jar version and that works good. But i want to use the settempdir() function and i must build them self inside the file, when I try to do this, I can not change the class inside the jar file.

the sourcecode of Aquery is https://github.com/androidquery/androidquery and i have insert it into Android Studio, i have change the code from this link https://github.com/androidquery/androidquery/pull/38 but i can not make a jar file. i see no gradle tab on the right.

Can i use it without making a jar of it?

Greathings christophe

Comment: do you port your AQuery Eclipse project to Android Studio project structure?

Comment: g2o, i  have download a repo from git and open it as a project file

Answer (score 0):

If you choose `Build project` you should have an `aar` file in the projects build folder which you can use just like a `jar` file.

Comment: how do i do that? i have maven in android studio